# Function to calculate average of Sum of all elements in sub-matrix

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, matrix, submatrix

---

I want to make a function that take three arguments

1. 2-D array. (int array[rows][cols])
2. an integer. (int n)
3. address of array[i][j].

Means my function prototype should look like this `double Sub_avg(int arr[rows][cols], int n, int *arr[i][j])`

---

**Function Explanation**

- first argument is 2D array that represents data which is going to be processed.
- Here `n` stands for *n x n* matrix means the dimension of square matrix whose average of all elements is required.
- The last argument `int arr[i][j]` is the address of first element of sub matrix.

---

**Sample Input**

- for example let us take 3x3 matrix,
- [image]
- I want to calculate for the sub matrix
- [image: List item]

---

**Output**

- then the function would return 8.25 that is (8 + 7 + 9 + 9)/4.

---

1. Is there any library function or template for this kind of calculations?
2. My main concern is how to pass a 2D array at run-time because user is going to enter the dimensions of array.

Comment: The function needs `i` and `j` , not `int *a[l][j]` (what is this?)

Comment: *Is it possible in C++?* -- If the answer to that was "no", wouldn't that make C++ one of the weakest computer languages ever created?  Of course it's possible in C++.

Comment: Please, put a look at [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66931917/941531) of your task.

Comment: `int *a[i][j]` is the address of first element of sub-array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of cause usually in C++ you will use [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) to store arrays and pass them around. But if you really need to work with plain old arrays and pointers then I'm providing next my solution of your task. Also when passing plain arrays you may use templates magic but I thought you want to have something very simple.

I minimally modified your function interface to become enough to solve the task with plain arrays and pointers. You should pass array as `int const *`, because in C/C++ you can't pass `int arr[rows][cols]` without templates magic, also you have to pass `rows` and `cols` because function doesn't know dimensions of array, also instead of passing a pointer to sub-array you should pass `sub_row` and `sub_col` position inside array.

Also I decided to implement `Sub_avg2()` function, which is very close to interface of your function, but it is more high-level and complex, because it uses templates. Also because of templates it means that your function's body should be placed only into header `.h` file of your library, body should be available as source at compile time. But extra bonus is that this function does extra compile time automatic work of passing array dimensions around.

Also you can notice that I do extra out of bounds checking in my code and returning 0 in case of error.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7VTbbqMwEH3nK2ZVtTKFNmmqbi@QfEBf9xGhiBiSdUpMhE0rbcq3pzM2BDdNtdr3tUAe7DkHz5wj8@32ipeZXO33Z0LysskLiEWldF1km5nnKZ1pwSGvmkVZwK9mMc9eV0xIDbySSsMlZHUdAi3U1ZuyEa/KLpJ2UojD7eEDM3zYeYBDLIH9QBJ4fzcUEMOYYiLpY9kHHZH7iXnHuwECZpbMSbKrROubH9OoC93UEsYRjEbw3GBBVYPvEhZVI3MF/HfBX4RcXRtE1wXVbGCKGLO2rGpgSvwp5hqEWcYpBhlBEIjhR27a2qat@7T1kEaD6IMp9TVhQ0XCx16bngRORevUnqKrg6Cj7phMIkD6kdd6ni422zLTJO0XoWanNZ44IrMLPIyfEC5NCJN@Urd3gqKsXtVBdayW0RZcAfEk4xQfH89pbdIXczrr3GRF/53yF6c4RkmTf/YHqbXJhGSufFZW05sp3Ia2zSaSOE1CR98bV8ab6EBBJ3Ncg5u7HeLvQvjZhrDD@SGE@y58xKdtLVjp/OmJU4fj@HDrkCMvfXPfWAtbA8lwuF8OdwvCDEch8/J7ygkzbMhw4TTx0MD0mKf19vsP)

```
#include <iostream>

static double Sub_avg(int const * arr, int rows, int cols, int n, int sub_row, int sub_col) {
    if (!arr || rows < 0 || cols < 0 || n < 0 || sub_row < 0 || sub_col < 0 || sub_row + n > rows || sub_col + n > cols)
        return 0; // Just out of bounds checking. Return error.
    double sum = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        for (size_t j = 0; j < n; ++j)
            sum += arr[(sub_row + i) * cols + sub_col + j];
    return sum / double(n * n);
}

template <int rows, int cols>
static double Sub_avg2(int const (&arr)[rows][cols], int n, int const * sarr) {
    int sub_row = (sarr - &arr[0][0]) / cols, sub_col = (sarr - &arr[0][0]) % cols;
    if (!arr || rows < 0 || cols < 0 || n < 0 || sub_row < 0 || sub_col < 0 || sub_row + n > rows || sub_col + n > cols)
        return 0; // Just out of bounds checking. Return error.
    double sum = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        for (size_t j = 0; j < n; ++j)
            sum += arr[sub_row + i][sub_col + j];
    return sum / double(n * n);
}

int main() {
    int const rows = 3, cols = 3, n = 2, sub_row = 1, sub_col = 1;
    int arr[rows][cols] = {{3, 5, 6}, {5, 8, 7}, {5, 9, 9}};
    std::cout << Sub_avg((int*)arr, rows, cols, n, sub_row, sub_col) << std::endl;
    std::cout << Sub_avg2(arr, n, &arr[sub_row][sub_col]) << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
8.25
8.25
```

Comment: Can you give some more example with templates? Eager to know something new, thank you.

Comment: @setller There are many resources about templates in internet, just search in Google for `c++ templates`. For example one simple tutorial [is here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/templates-cpp/).

Comment: @setller Also if my answer was correct and/or helpful to you then don't forget to accept and/or UpVote it. To Accept an answer go to beginning of answer, and to the left from it there is a Check-Mark, also to Up-Vote in the same place there is Up-Arrow. You can do both Accepting and Up-Voting.